# reconstruct matrix with non zero values

Tags: c++, matrix

Ive been asked to write a program to reconstruct a matrix using only non zero values.

I have been given an example input:

> ```
> 2.4 0 5.6 0
> 0 11.5 1.3 5.4
> 5.6 1.3 0 0
> 0 5.4 0 0
> ```

And it gets reconstructed into this:

> ```
> 4
> 2 1 2.4 3 5.6
> 3 2 11.5 3 1.3 4 5.4
> 2 1 5.6 2 1.3
> 1 2 5.4
> 8
> ```

I understand the first value 4 is the number of nodes and the last value 8 is the total of the non zero elements. I also understand that the first value of each row is the total of the non zero elements in each row and this value is also used to add extra elements to the row e.g in row two there are 3 non zero values so the first element in the row will be 3 and there will be 6 following elements (3+3).
What I cant understand is why they are jumbled like in the first row using a 1 & 3?
Could someone offer an explanation to this?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `2 1 2.4 3 5.6` mean that in this row there are two non-zero elements, the element at column index 1 is 2.4 and the element at column index 3 is 5.6?

Comment: You have been asked -- presumably by somebody (a teacher, a boss, a client)   Rather than having us try to mind-read this unknown person, I suggest that you ask them for clarification.